# How to use NSScrollView in XCode 7+ Storyboards?

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard, nsscrollview

I have never used NSScrollView, but looking at the tutorials, I thought It should be easy to figure out.

However, It turns out to be not intuitive at all. I pulled a ScrollView. It did not have any scrollers, though I have then enabled. No place to set ContentArea or of some sort. And. it has a clipview inside it and that clip view has another view inside. You can only add a view inside that third View.

[image]

So I thought of adding an Image view inside and it doesn't work at all. When I run, it doesn't show up. Nothing.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the [DropBox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdd1t6tvctgbs1d/NSScrollViewExperiment.zip?dl=0) to project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 2 steps.

Fist you should position you view towards left top corner of clip view. Add 2 constraints as shown on the picture:

[image]

Then make sure you picture expands to parent view but set priority to 750 so it would not expand entire window:

[image]

Then it will look correct:

[image]

Here is your fixed project:

https://github.com/emankovski/NSScrollViewExperiment

PS: You also forgot to drag your picture to the assets catalog. I did that in the fixed project.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Would you know, why calling "scrollView.verticalScrollElasticity = NSScrollElasticity.None" or the horizontal counter part has no effect? When you leave the scroller to decelerate, you see the elastic behaviour..

Comment: I only create UI in IB so when I set no elasticy in IB for that Scroll View everything works just file. I am not sure why it does not work for you when you set in the code.

Comment: @EugeneMankovski I tried it works well for image view but tried the same constraints for custom view but doesn't work it says view needs position for x and y. I Wanna make a custom view with many items scrollable